# Why does this site look like Stack Overflow?

Tags: discussion, design

Why does this site look exactly like stackoverflow.com?

Furthermore why does this site not validate fields before it does human verification with the image. This took 15 mins to get posted when it should have taken 2 minutes.

Answer (score 11):

Programmers Stack Exchange is one of the 84 (currently) Q&A sites of the Stack Exchange network, that includes Stack Overflow. You can find more details about Stack Exchange at [stackexchange.com](http://stackexchange.com/) and more specifically:

- [About Stack Exchange](http://stackexchange.com/about)
- [List of all Stack Exchange sites](http://stackexchange.com/sites#answers)

If you are interested in finding out what Programmers is about, you should read:

- Our [about page](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/about),
- Our [FAQ](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/faq), and
- Our frequently asked Meta questions, assembled in this [index](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1647/25936).

As for the "human verification" thingy, it pop ups occasionally (and it's a bit annoying!), but it pops up less frequently if you register for an account. If you already have a Stack Overflow account, you can use the same credentials for Programmers, and your two accounts will be automatically linked.

Comment: +1, much clearer.

Answer (score 5):

Because it's a companion site to [StackOverflow](http://www.stackoverflow.com/), but with a different purpose, as evidenced by the [FAQ](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/faq).

Both are managed by [StackExchange](http://www.stackexchangecom/), like many other sites, which are hosted under their own top-level domain (like [MathOverflow](http://www.mathoverflow.com/)) or a sub-domain of `stackexchange.com`.

See [the list of all sites on the StackExchange network](http://stackexchange.com/sites).

Furthermore, new sites appear regularly spawned by the [StackExchange Area 51](http://area51.stackexchange.com/) based on community involvement, and may then undergo a "beta" period to be live-tested until they become a site of their own.